# The music application doesn't open

Tags: music

The music app doesn't start anymore , everything else is working fine. I tried restarting and updating elementary but didn't help. I am an amateur user I don't tweak my elementary I just use it for entertainment "movies , music , browsing ". so my elementary is almost at default settings.

[image]

```
kerollos@Home:~$ noise
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 18:43:13.578628] Application.vala:155: Music version: 0.3.1 
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 18:43:13.578692] Application.vala:157: Kernel version: 3.16.0-53-generic Failed to register: Timeout was reached
```

Comment: Open terminal and run `noise` and let me know :)

Comment: this happened 
kerollos@Home:~$ noise
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 18:43:13.578628] Application.vala:155: Music version: 0.3.1
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 18:43:13.578692] Application.vala:157: Kernel version: 3.16.0-53-generic

Failed to register: Timeout was reached